# Regex IP wildcard Conversion

Tags: regex

I need to convert the following to Regex.  I need the second, and third octets to be a wildcard.  I am awful with Regex as I rarely ever need to use it. I have searched the web for a solution. Can someone help with this?

10.(Wildcard).(Wildcard).248

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider brushing up on regular expressions as wildcards are usually one of the first things you learn.  Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to get you started.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Do you care whether the second and third octets are really octets (i.e. in the range 0-255), or just whether they're strings of digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10\.\d+\.\d+\.248
```

'\.' matches with '.', '\d' matches with any digit. '\d+' matches with 1 or more digits.
Other characters matches with themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! All of these worked great for what I needed.

Comment: `10.99999.99999.248` could also match with this. Do you want the values to be in the range 0-255 like @ZeroPiraeus asked in a comment, or can any numbers be used?

Comment: It depends on the source and format data. If you parse user's input, use difficult pattern, but if you parse logs, you can use simple pattern. It's clearer.

Answer (score 4):

**Short and sweet:**
`10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.248` will get you pretty close, and is relatively simple.

- Escape the dot with `\.` to prevent it from matching any character
- Use `\d` to match any digit character
- Use `{1,3}` to limit the number of consecutive digits to 1, 2, or 3

**More complicated, but more exact:**
To only match numbers between 0 and 255, you could replace `\d{1,3}` with [`([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html):

```
10\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.248
```

- or -

```
10(\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){2}\.248
```

**Testing/developing regex patterns in the future**
There are a lot of regex tester websites out there. I personally use [RexexHero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/) since I develop .Net applications, but there are other more generic options too such as [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the dot metacharacter with a backslash, but something like this will work:

```
10\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.248
```

Note: this pattern isn't bulletproof.  It doesn't check if the IP address is valid, it only checks if it matches an IP-like pattern.  For example, it will match `10.999.999.248`.

Comment: This would allow `10.999.999.248` if you don't limit the first digit to be limited to 0 or 1.

Comment: @OnlineCop - Correct, but given OP's current knowledge of regular expressions, I didn't want to make the answer needlessly complicated.  (e.g.: The first digit can only be 0, 1, 2 if it's three digits, the second digit can be 0-9 unless it's three digits and the first digit is a 2, etc)